# How I can modify this code to introducing just the values how not exists in another table

Tags: sql

I try to use the next code for introducing users how are in glob table, but they don't exists in tlp table, but every time when I run the program, introducing the duplicate value for one user. I don't understand why .

```
INSERT INTO tlp
            (given_name, 
             namel, 
             email, poreclat) 
SELECT first_name, 
       namel, 
       mail, porecla 

FROM   glob 
WHERE 


(( NOT EXISTS (SELECT email 
                     FROM   tlp 
                     WHERE  glob.mail = tlp.email ) 
         AND glob.mail IS NOT NULl)
          and glob.country='Romania'
         ) 
        or (( NOT EXISTS (SELECT namel 
                         FROM   tlp 
                         WHERE  glob.namel = tlp.namel
                        ) 
                      and  glob.country='Romania'))
        or ( exists (select given_name
                  from tlp
                  where (glob.first_name not like '07_%') and 
                 glob.first_name not like 'car%' and
                 glob.first_name not like 'TR_%'
                 )
                    );
```

here I created the tables

```
create table glob
 ( persone_id number not null ENABLE,
 first_name varchar(10),
 namel varchar(10),
 mail varchar(50),
 country varchar(10),
 porecla varchar (10),

  create_date date default sysdate);

  insert into glob(persone_id,first_name, namel, mail) values (1, 'daniela', 'pop', 'dany_pop93@yahoo.com');
  insert into glob(persone_id,first_name, namel,mail, country) values (2, 'razvan', 'cirstescu', null, 'Romania');
  insert into glob (persone_id,first_name, namel, country) values (3, 'darius', 'moldovan', 'Germany' );
  insert into glob (persone_id,first_name, namel, mail, country) values  (4, 'alex', 'duta', null, 'Romania');
  insert into glob(persone_id,first_name, namel, mail, country) values (5, 'edith', null, 'edith@yahoo', 'Romania');
  insert into glob(persone_id,first_name, namel, mail) values (6, 'madi', 'todea', 'madi@yahoo');
  insert into glob(persone_id,first_name, namel, mail) values (7, 'madi', 'todea', 'madi@yahoo');
  insert into glob(persone_id,first_name, namel, mail) values (8, 'madi', 'todea', 'madi@yahoo');
```

the second table is:

```
create table tlp
  ( given_name varchar(10),
   namel varchar (10),
   email varchar (50),
   poreclat varchar(10),

   create_date date default sysdate);

   insert into TLP(given_name, namel, email) values ('daniela', 'pop', 'dany_pop93@yahoo.com');
 insert into TLP(given_name, namel, email) values ('andrei', 'pop', 'andrei@yahoo');
```

And now I observed, this code introducing duplicate values .

My question is : How I can make this code to not introducing duplicate values ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should create an **unique constraint** to avoid any **duplicate rows** from being inserted.

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE tlp ADD CONSTRAINT tlp_unq UNIQUE (given_name, namel, email, poreclat, create_date);

Table altered.
```

Use **MERGE** to do an upsert, it is easy to understand and quite verbose. The only thing to keep in mind is use **DISTINCT** to pick **distinct rows** from `glob` table. The problem is that you already have **duplicate rows** in your **source table** `glob`.

```
SQL> MERGE INTO tlp d
  2  USING (SELECT DISTINCT first_name, namel, mail, porecla, create_date FROM glob) s
  3  ON(d.given_name = s.first_name) -- join key(s)
  4  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  5     UPDATE SET d.namel = s.namel,
  6                d.email = s.mail,
  7                d.poreclat = s.porecla,
  8                d.create_date = s.create_date
  9  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 10  INSERT (given_name,
 11               namel,
 12               email, poreclat, create_date)
 13  VALUES (s.first_name,
 14         s.namel,
 15         s.mail, s.porecla, s.create_date );

6 rows merged.
```

Let's verify the table:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM tlp;

GIVEN_NAME NAMEL      EMAIL                PORECLAT   CREATE_DATE
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- -----------
alex       duta                                       11-AUG-15
madi       todea      madi@yahoo                      11-AUG-15
edith                 edith@yahoo                     11-AUG-15
darius     moldovan                                   11-AUG-15
razvan     cirstescu                                  11-AUG-15
daniela    pop        dany_pop93@yahoo.com            11-AUG-15
andrei     pop        andrei@yahoo                    11-AUG-15

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Update** OP wants to know how to filter the rows, i.e. **conditional INSERTS and UPDATES using WHERE clause**.

You could simply add the WHERE clause to the update and insert statements:

For example

```
MERGE INTO test1 a
  USING all_objects b
    ON (a.object_id = b.object_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET a.status = b.status
    WHERE  b.status != 'VALID'
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (object_id, status)
    VALUES (b.object_id, b.status)
    WHERE  b.status != 'VALID';
```

See more examples [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g).

Comment: tank you for this answer, but I have another problem, I don't have permission to alter the table

Comment: @PopDaniela No problem, that is just an extra constraint to avoid any intentional duplicate insert. My solution would work without the alter statement also. The main focus is on the **MERGE** statement.

Comment: and where I supposed to put this statement   and ( exists (select given_name
                  from tlp
                  where (glob.first_name not like '07_%') and 
                 glob.first_name not like 'car%' and
                 glob.first_name not like 'TR_%'
                 )
                    );

Comment: Simply add it to the **WHERE** clause to both the UPDATE and INSERT statements. For example see https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g

Answer (score 0):

Try to use distinct 
+ updated where conditions

```
 INSERT INTO tlp
            (given_name, 
             namel, 
             email, poreclat) 
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, 
       namel, 
       mail, porecla 

FROM   glob 
(( NOT EXISTS (SELECT email 
                     FROM   tlp 
                     WHERE  glob.mail = tlp.email ) 
         AND glob.mail IS NOT NULl)
          and glob.country='Romania'
         ) 
        or (( NOT EXISTS (SELECT namel 
                         FROM   tlp 
                         WHERE  glob.namel = tlp.namel
                        ) 
                      and  glob.country='Romania'))
        or ( exists (select given_name
                  from tlp
                  where (glob.first_name not like '07_%') and 
                 glob.first_name not like 'car%' and
                 glob.first_name not like 'TR_%'
                 )
)
and (first_name, namel, mail, porecla) not in (select given_name, namel, email, poreclat from tlp )
```

Comment: is not so easy, because, where I have the same values for first_name and namel, but email is different, this code omit that row

Comment: But you also get mail from glob in this select and if it'll be different - you'll get all values for it (even with distinct)

Comment: run this script for two times and you see how duplicate values appear

Comment: Even with your where conditions?

Comment: whit my condition introduce one row duplicate, more exactly the row of edith name

Comment: So, may be problem with your where conditions? Updated solution